# jQuery BMI Math Calculation

Tags: jquery, math, formula

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I want the user to be able to enter their information into the BMI (Body mass index) calculator and for the formula to output the users BMI answer correctly.

**Current Problems:**

When entering the following values e.g:

- Feet `5`
- Inches `3`
- Stone `13`
- Pounds `4`

The formula outputs `130758` instead of `32.9` which is the correct value.

**JS:**

```
  var feet = $('#feet').val(); // e.g 5
  var inches = $('#inches').val(); // e.g 3
  var stone = $('#stone').val(); // e.g 13
  var pounds = $('#pounds').val(); // e.g 4
  var imperialCalc = Math.round(stone*14+pounds/(feet*12+inches)*(feet*12+inches))*703; // BMI Formula
  console.log(imperialCalc); // e.g 32.9
```

**BMI Formula:**

```
stone*14+pounds/(feet*12+inches)*(feet*12+inches))*703
```

**BMI Example:**
http://www.aviva.co.uk/health-insurance/home-of-health/tools-and-calculators/bmi.html

**Thank you in advance for all your help!**

Comment: Looks like you're concatenating strings instead of adding numbers.

Comment: Where did you get the formula from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

`var imperialCalc = ((stone*14)+pounds)/((feet*12+inches)*(feet*12+inches))*703;`

Round according to your desired digits

Comment: I'm now getting 3.526513370131102

Comment: Yes sorry please see changes, had parentheses in wrong spot.

Comment: The value is now 32.944822373393805, I can see it getting closer! How do I now go around making it 32.9 ?

Comment: You could do imperialCalc = imperialCalc.toFixed(1); or you could just do it upon use, console.log(imperialCalc.toFixed(1));